# How to initialize nested interfaces in TypeScript component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am very new to TypeScript and Angular (version is the latest) and I need help. I have declared 2 interfaces, one nested within the other and is an array of the nested interface.

```
export interface ModelOuter {
  modelInners?: ModelInner[];
  errorMessage : string;
}

export interface ModelInner {
 prop1: string;
}
```

Now I am trying to call a service within my component, and this is my code,

```
export MyComponent implements OnInit {

modelOuter : ModelOuter | undefined; //I need help here
modelInner: ModelInner[] |undefined; //Do I really need this? If yes,how do I initialize it?

//other ngOnInit code block goes here and within ngOnInit I am calling the below block
this.myService.getModels()
.subscribe((data: ModelOuter)=> {
       this.modelOuter : data;

       if (data.modelInner.length > 0) {
         this.modelInner = data.modelInner;
         modelOuter.modelInner = this.modelInner;
       }
}
```

No matter how much I try, on my template HTML, I am getting modelInner is Undefined error. My question is, how do I initialize both my outer interface and the nested interface in one line within my component and how do I assign both these objects within my service.subscribe block, so that I don't get the undefined error on my template HTML?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Checking the presence of `modelInner` in the if condition should help

```
this.myService.getModels()
.subscribe((data: ModelOuter)=> {
       this.modelOuter : data;

       if (data?.modelInner && data.modelInner.length > 0) {
         this.modelInner = data.modelInner;
         modelOuter.modelInner = this.modelInner;
       }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Even though this definitely helped to ensure preventing errors, I was more wanting to figure out how I can get past the Undefined error. I finally was able to figure out. Thanks though

Comment: One thing I did though was change the optional modelInners array property to a required property.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the initialization right finally.

```
modelOuter : ModelOuter | undefined; //I need help here
modelInner: ModelInner[] |undefined; //Do I really need this? If yes,how do I initialize it?
```

should be replaced by:

```
modelOuter: ModelOuter  = {
errorMessage: '',
modelInners : []
}
```

and then in my subscribe block, I just need

```
this.modelOuter = data;
```